# MySQL subquery fetch only latest value from JOIN table

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query. The user_extra table can return multiple values for a given user_id. I would like only the latest a.session_date value from user_extra.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (user_id) user_id, a.value  
 FROM user_reg ap 
 JOIN user_extra a USING (user_id) 
WHERE ap.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-10' AND a.session_date<='2017-01-01'
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ap.user_id, ap1.value
from user_reg ap
inner join (
    select user_id, max(session_date) as MaxDate, value
    from user_extra 
    group by user_id
) ap1 on ap.user_id = ap1.user_id and ap.date = ap1.MaxDate
```

It will give maximum session date for single user id.

Comment: The select distinct in this has been removed, how can I retain the distinct on user_id?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out I added the DISTINCT clause in the select and in the inner join select user_id i changed it to user_id as uid then it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to join to a subquery which finds the latest records.  This is probably the best way to go here as MySQL does not have analytic functions available.  In this case, we can add one more join to your query to restrict the `user_extra` table to having the record corresponding to the most recent session for each user.

```
SELECT
    ur.user_id,
    ue1.value
FROM user_reg ur
INNER JOIN user_extra ue1
    ON ur.user_id = ue1.user_id AND
       ue1.session_date <= '2017-01-01'
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(session_date) AS max_session_date
    FROM user_extra
    GROUP BY user_id
) ue2
    ON ue1.user_id = ue2.user_id AND
       ue1.session_date = ue2.max_session_date
WHERE
    ur.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-10';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to get a list of all the values of a user use:

```
SELECT A.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(B.value) LIST_OF_VALUES FROM
(SELECT user_id, value FROM user_reg 
WHERE session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-10'
GROUP BY user_id, value) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, MAX(session_date) FROM user_extra 
WHERE session_date<='2017-01-01' GROUP BY user_id) B
ON A.user_id=B.user_id
GROUP BY A.user_id;
```

But if you would want to get the total values of a user use:

```
SELECT A.user_id, SUM(B.value) SUM_OF_VALUES FROM
(SELECT user_id, value FROM user_reg 
WHERE session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-10'
GROUP BY user_id, value) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, MAX(session_date) FROM user_extra 
WHERE session_date<='2017-01-01' GROUP BY user_id) B
ON A.user_id=B.user_id
GROUP BY A.user_id;
```